# wrong AUC when using caTools in R

Tags: r, auc

I was using the caTools package in R to get AUC in R. Only now I found out that it returns the same AUC when the probabilities are flipped. This is not really correct (see example below). Is there any theoretical reason where this makes sense?

```
library(caTools)
p <- runif(100)
y <- rep(0,100)
y[p>0.5] <- 1
caTools::colAUC(p,y)
#        [,1]
#0 vs. 1    1
caTools::colAUC(1-p,y)
#        [,1]
#0 vs. 1    1
```

When using the ROCR package the results look as expected.

```
library(ROCR)
pred.rocr <- ROCR::prediction(p, y)
auc.perf  <- ROCR::performance(pred.rocr, measure = "auc")
unlist(auc.perf@y.values)
#[1] 1
pred.rocr <- ROCR::prediction(1-p, y)
auc.perf  <- ROCR::performance(pred.rocr, measure = "auc")
unlist(auc.perf@y.values)
#[1] 0
```

I will appreciate any suggestions, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is because in the last line in `colAUC`, it returns `Auc = pmax(Auc, 1 - Auc)`. I don't think there is anything wrong (you just need to be aware of it). In fact, the author is aware of the difference and did a comparison of ROC function with other packages (see this link: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2005-September/079513.html).

Comment: thanks for your reply. The documentation also mentions "Returned AUC is always bigger than 0.5, which is equivalent of testing for each feature colAUC(x,y) and colAUC(-x,y) and returning the value of the bigger one.", didn't read it carefully enough.